# jQuery UI Autosearch To Search For Multiple Strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to add some functionality to the jQuery UI autosearch function. The problem I want to solve is to allow a user to enter text in any order that will search through a list of terms and display suggestions. For example, suppose I have the following terms:

```
the brown cow jumped over the moon
the blue cow watched in horror
the red cow simply laughed 
the green cow got sick at such a sight
the yellow cow lost 5 bucks to the black cow
the black cow smiled at his fortune

If the user types in "the cow", I would expect the autocomplete feature to list all the results.
If I type in "brown moon", I would expect the first result to appear.
If I type in "fortune smiled", the last result would appear.
```

Basically this behavior allows the user to type in any string in any order and get search results.

Here's what I'm thinking. I need to add a callback function in either the "open" or "search" events and manipulate the results there. Here's my code so far:

```
$(function ()
{
    var data =
    [
        "the brown cow jumped over the moon",
        "the blue cow watched in horror",
        "the red cow simply laughed ",
        "the green cow got sick at such a sight",
        "the yellow cow lost 5 bucks to the black cow",
        "the black cow smiled at his fortune"
    ];

    $(".text-search").autocomplete(
    {
        autoFocus: true,
        source: data,
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        open: function (e, ui)
        {
            debugger;
            // what should i do here?
        },
        search: function (e, ui)
        {
            debugger;
            // what should i do here?
        }
    });
});

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="autocomplete">Autocomplete: </label>
    <input class="text-search">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to semantically search based on the search criteria or how to use the autocomplete to call a server url to get results and render the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your own regular expression based on the text the user entered. You can then use this regular expression to test each item in the candidate list:

```
$(".text-search").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var regexStr = "\\b(" + $.map($.trim(request.term).split(" "), function(term) {
            return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($.trim(term))
        }).join("|") + ")\\b",
        matcher = new RegExp(regexStr);

        response($.grep(data, function(value) {
            return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
        }));
    },
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 2
});
```

The regular expression piece looks cryptic, but it's just generating an expression using alternation (`|`). For example, if you type `brown cow`, `\b(brown|cow)\b` is generated which will match any string with "brown" or "cow".

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hTfj9/